# Cancel Event Listener After Blur If Next Event is a Specific Click event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a textarea which is used in edit mode and I defined a listener on **blur** of this in order to exiting edit mode.

Everything was working as a charm until I decided to add an emoji support on this textarea. The problem is when user wants to click on emoji popup handler blur event triggers and cancels edit mode.

I am trying to find a way to recognize user clicked on **emoji popup handler** not wants to exit edit mode.

Is it possible to:

> 1-Recognize next event in js event loop after blur

or

> 2-Discover the element which is clicked and caused blur trigger

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the blur event with a window click event like this.

```
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   if ((event.target !== textarea) && (event.target !== emoji)) {
       console.log(event.target);
       // Exit edit mode
   }
});
```